# Как извлекаются данные из QDataStream

Tags: c++, qt, потоки-данных, qt4, клиент

Здравствуйте. В книге Макса Шлее «Qt4» встретил следующий пример:

```
void MyServer::slotReadClient()
{
    QTcpSocket* pClientSocket = (QTcpSocket*)sender();
    QDataStream in(pClientSocket);
    in.setVersion(QDataStream::Qt_4_2);
    for(;;) {
        if (!m_nNextBlockSize) {
            if (pClientSocket->bytesAvailable() < sizeof(quint16)) {
                break;
            }
            in >> m_nNextBlockSize;
        }

        if(pClientSocket->bytesAvailable() < m_nNextBlockSize) {
            break;
        }
        QTime   time;
        QString str;
        in >> time >> str;

        QString strMessage = 
            time.toString() + " " + "Client has sended - " + str;
        m_ptxt->append(strMessage);

        m_nNextBlockSize = 0;

        sendToClient(pClientSocket,
                     "Server Response: Received \"" + str + "\""
                    );
    }
}
```

Вкратце объясню код.

1. В сокет клиента приходят какие-то данные.
2. У `QTcpServer срабатывает сигнал`readyRead()`.
3. Код сверху вызывается, будучи подключенным к вышеуказанному сигналу в качестве слота.
4. Получаем указатель на источник сигнала и приводим его к `QTcpSocket`.
5. Открываем `QDataStream`, привязывая его у полученному `QTcpSocket`.
6. Входим в бесконечный цикл.
7. Если доступно для чтения `sizeof(quint16)` байт, то есть получены данные размера с интересующий нас блок, читаем их; иначе выполняем `break` и ждем следующего `readyRead()`.
8. После того, как мы считали блок, сравниваем доступное количество байт с размером следующего блока. Если доступное количество байт больше или равно нужного нам, то мы читаем `QTime` и `QString`.

Вот у меня **вопрос**: как поток знает сколько байт нужно записать в `QTime` и `QString`? А если бы я считывал `QStringList` из потока? Мы ведь не указываем, что именно нужно считать в `m_nNextBlockSize`, а просто читаем. Размер доступного блока может же быть насколько угодно больше `m_nNextBlockSize`. Может быть для `QString` он и остановится на `\0`, но что тогда для `QTime` и `QStringList`? Для `QStringList`, наверное, нужно как-то задать, сколько нужно считать, верно?

Вот, собственно, мой код. Он корректен или нет?

```
QDataStream in(&tcp);
in.setVersion(QDataStream::Qt_DefaultCompiledVersion);

if (!blockSize)
    if(tcp.bytesAvailable() < sizeof(quint16))
        return;
in >> blockSize;

if (tcp.bytesAvailable() < blockSize)
    return;
QStringList str;
in >> str;

ui->listWidget->addItems(str);
blockSize = 0;
```

Answer (score 3):

Поток не знает, сколько байт нужно записать в QString. Сериализатор QString знает сам. Если посмотреть, как именно записывается QString, то можно увидеть, что вначале он записывает 4 байта длины, а потом собственно саму строку (я это все наблюдал в хекс редакторе). Естественно, когда нужно прочитать, то вначале читаются эти 4 байта и длина строки стразу стает известна. И проблем прочитать уже нет.

QStringList работает где то также (его я не смотрел, но документация это [подтвержает](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/datastreamformat.html) - он тут как QList).

QTime и подобные поступают также. Его размер более-менее стандартный. По документации там 4 байта.

С кодом - должен работать, главное не забывайте обнулить blockSize перед первым вызовом, а то будет "странное". И даже, если QStringList записывает свой размер, хуже не будет от того, что Вы записали свои 2 байта в начало (я бы 4 писал). Допустим, в будущем, Вы захотите писать не только QStringList, а ещё один qint32 (ну мало чего). В этом случае старый код, который о этих 4 байтах в конце ничего не знает, сможет корректно прочитать данные (главное добавить небольшое чтение в конец, которое будет "дочитывать хвост").

Comment: Не совсем понял к чему qint32. Я не собираюсь передавать блоки размерностью больше quint16. quint16 служит для определение размера передаваемого блока, а не размера QStringList.

Comment: Ваш код - Вам и решать

Comment: И я не совсем понял, почему в этом коде автор делает цикл? Понятно что если еще есть данные от этого сокета, то их надо бы считать. Но ведь при пересылке данных, каждый раз испускается сигнал, и даже если код слота сейчас еще выполняется, то слот будет потом и так вызван. Так зачем тут тогда цикл?

Comment: Представьте, что каждый раз приходит по две записи. И если скорость потока достаточная, то входящий буфер будет переполняется.

Comment: Представил. Но не понял. Почему с циклом он переполняться не будет?

Comment: Тут тонко. Открываем документацию на readyRead (она тут QIODevice::readyRead) и там сказано, что этот сигнал нужно эмитить только если пришли **новые данные**. А эмитить, если есть данные в буфере - не нужно. То есть, если данные были прочитаны не все, и в буфере есть ещё данные, то можно не эмитить сигнал.

С циклом также возможно переполнение. Но в этом случае уже будет упираться в скорость обработки. А вот без цикла, если данные приходят по несколько записей, то переполниться очень легко.

Comment: Всмысле емитить? Я ничего не испускаю, я только подключил сигнал к слоту. И вот что я читаю:
 It will only be emitted again once new data is available, such as when a new payload of network data has arrived on your network socket, or when a new block of data has been appended to your device.

Comment: В документации QAbstractSocket
The readyRead() signal is emitted every time a new chunk of data has arrived.

Comment: я не сказал, что Вы должны эмитить. 

Собственно английский текст детально все и рассказывает.